# I need help on configuring mod_wsgi and Django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Apache & mod_wsgi are configured correctly (I've created a hello 
world .html apache file and a hello world mod_wsgi application with 
no problems). I now need my Django app to work with my django.wsgi 
file. What makes me think that it's not recognizing my wsgi file is that I 
went into my django.wsgi file I created and completely deleted all of 
the code in the file and restarted Apache and it still gives me the 
same page (a listing of the files from Django app, not my actual 
Django application. Configuring Apache and mod_wsgi went really well 
but I'm at a loss of how to fix this. Here are some details:

Here is my current django.wsgi file:

```
import os 
import sys 

sys.path.append('/srv/www/duckling.org/store/') 

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'store.settings' 

import django.core.handlers.wsgi 

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've tried a few different versions of the django.wsgi file 
(including a version like the one over at http://www.djangoproject.com/). 
This version of my wsgi is from here: 
http://library.linode.com/frameworks/django-apache-mod-wsgi/ubuntu-10...

Also, here is my vhost apache configuration file below. I think these 
are the main files that are suppose to do the job for me. Let me know if 
you see any errors in what I'm doing and what else I might do to fix 
this. The django app runs fine on the django's built-in development 
server so I'm thinking it *might have* something with my paths. 
No errors in my apache error.log file as well. It's acting as there's 
no problem at all, which is not the case...the project isn't loading, 
like I said just a listing of my files and directories of my Django 
project. Here is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
ServerAdmin hi@duckling.org
ServerName duckling.org
ServerAlias www.duckling.org

DocumentRoot /srv/www/duckling.org/store/

<Directory /srv/www/duckling.org/store/>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /srv/www/duckling.org/store/static/

<Directory /srv/www/duckling.org/store/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias store/ /srv/www/duckling.org/store/wsgi-scripts/django.wsgi
<Directory /srv/www/wsgi-scripts>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here are versions of the stack that I'm using, I saw over at the 
mod_wsgi site that you all would like the versions of what I'm using 
on the server:

```
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch 
mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.5 mod_wsgi/2.8
```

thanks, 
j.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should definitely not keep your Django files under your DocumentRoot. There's no need for them to be there, and it's a potential security risk - as you've seen, your current misconfiguration allows Apache to serve up your files directly: an attacker could guess that and download your settings.py, complete with your database password.

So, get rid of that DocumentRoot directive completely, as well as the first Directory section which allows direct access to `/srv/www/duckling.org/store/`. (You probably don't need the one serving up `/srv/www/wsgi-scripts` either.) That should make things a bit better.

By the way, this configuration will serve your website under `duckling.org/store` - is that what you want? If you want it under the root, you should just use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/duckling.org/store/wsgi-scripts/django.wsgi
```

Comment: Hmm, from what I understood the DocumentRoot directive is mandatory. There's another one in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file but I thought I was suppose to use a vhost to configure things and leave the default alone. I'm probably just confused as heck at this point though. :D Regardless, after those changes I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: It may well be mandatory, it just shouldn't be the location of your Python code. Set it to the static directory, if necessary. In any case, what does your Apache error log show?

Comment: There are no errors in server logs, that's what is killing me. It's acting like every thing is fine but it's not. I'll change that DocumentRoot directive immediately though, I wouldn't want to me serving up my Python code for everyone out there. :/